# How to change the background colour of the cell above the edited cell (Javascript, Google Spreadsheets)

Tags: javascript, database, cell, edit

I apologize in advance for this question - it seems so basic but I just can't figure it out myself, or find anything anywhere on the internet that answers my question.

**My Background**

I'm generally used to using excel until very recently, when I moved jobs to a department that uses Google Docs. My knowledge of Javascript is very basic, based on the stuff I've come across during the past 4 weeks trying to do some basic code.

**Background of the sheet I'm working on**

We have a large sheet of names with associated info, input onto each row. So 1 row = 1 person. Each row goes from Column A to Column T.

My boss would like any historical data kept, very much like a database. I'm aware Spreadsheets isn't the best place for this, but my knowledge of database software is less than that of Javascript. What I've managed to do, as a temporary solution, is create an additional column (Column U: Archive) which cuts and pastes the entire row into a sheet named ARCHIVE when 'yes' is input. It also then deletes the empty row left behind, keeping the table nice and tidy.

See code here (sheet name changed to Sheet 1 for example purposes):

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "Sheet1" && r.getColumn() == 21 && r.getValue() == "yes") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

**What I would like to do now (and what I need the code for)**

My colleagues would like to be able to view the archive sheet and see, at-a-glance, which cell was changed. We thought the best and simplest way to do this would be to highlight the cell.

However, before we archive the row, we're having to copy it, insert a line below and paste the copied data. Then we change whichever cell has incorrect data, before archiving the row with the old data (so we have a record of all data held at any point during the sheet's life). In Column T, before archiving, we're also inputting today's date, so we know when the info was changed.

So - I need a code that can change the cell below the one that is being edited (this will contain the old data), but not for columns T or U (so A:S).

Like I said before, I apologise for what is likely a cack-handed way of doing things and asking a beginner question!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the revision history that is build in google spreadsheets a better solution to your problem? [https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843?hl=en](http://Isn't%20the%20revision%20history%20that%20is%20build%20in%20google%20spreadsheets%20a%20better%20solution%20to%20your%20problem?%20https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843?hl=en).

Comment: It's not ideal for our purposes, as on the archive page we would have the option of filtering (so we could view all of the changes for one set of data over time), and we would like to see which changes have been made all at once, rather than going into the revision history and finding the change on the right tab, etc. So much easier if we're able to highlight the change.

Comment: Probably worth adding that the 'data' refers to individual people, hence the need to filter the information on the archive tab.